# How to concatenate $HOME in the url in the Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, terminal, jenkins-pipeline

How can I concatenate `$HOME` in the URL in a Jenkins Pipeline? I currently have the following pipeline, and I want add my home path instead of hardcoding something like `/users/john`.

This is what I did, but I am getting an error that `HOME` is

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HOME for
>   class: groovy.lang.Binding

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        label {
            label ""
            customWorkspace "$HOME/qa-end-to-end"
        }
    }


  tools {nodejs "node"}

  stages {
        stage('Checkout App') {
            steps {
                dir("/$HOME/sfa") {
                echo "Building.."
                sh 'git reset --hard HEAD'
                sh 'git clean -f -d'
                sh 'git pull'
                }
                // build app
                dir("$HOMEsfa") {
                sh '$HOME/qa-end-to-end/App.sh'
                }

stage('Reports') {
            steps {
            script {
            allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk: '',
                    properties: [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [[path: 'target/allure-results']]
         ])
    }
    }


            }
        }
```

when i run this -

```
sh '${env.HOME}/qa-end-to-end/App.sh'
```

i get an error - bad substitution

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Your edit introduced incorrect inline code markup, missed typos and grammar mistakes, and didn't fix the formatting of the code block that was missing a line.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri I don't know what you mean... this isn't my question. I'm not sure you got *my* point.

Comment: It's wont harm to you even i edit the question. Jason_Jenkins has to decide either the question is in correct format or not even question is edited by some one like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access environment variables in pipeline steps with the env object eg like:

```
${env.HOME}
```

See an example from [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables)

```
Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "Running ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run this - sh '${env.HOME}/qa-end-to-end/App.sh' i get an error - bad substitution

Comment: also can you see my full pipeline above? i tried adding but getting the bad substitution error

Comment: i just added. take a look

Comment: Can you try changing the single quotes to double `sh "${env.HOME}/qa-end-to-end/App.sh"`

Comment: it works but one problem. it is killing my report and i do not see my last stage which is allure reporting

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by killing the report ? You mean the last stage of pipeline is not triggered? Why is the job failing when the script is triggered?

Comment: Why so? Is the pipeline failing or simply skips the last stage? Could be an issue with the script that results in pipeline failure?

Comment: the test in the pipeline fails and it is not skipping the last stage. But somehow it shows the build passed and when i go to the report. it is empty.

Comment: But that is out of scope for this question as your issue with using $home var is fixed now. So if the answer satisfies you, do accept it.

Comment: i saw that it is adding null in my code - /Users/john/.jenkins/null/qa-end-to-end/allure-report. This is why it is not producing report.